# Set HTML Background Color as JS Variable

Tags: html

I want to set a variable that's been set in JavaScript as an HTML page's background.

I'm making a Chrome new tab override, and part of it is generating a random colour hex to be the background.

After getting this problem, I decided to test it out:

```
<body style="background-color:colour;">
<script>
var colour = blue;
</script>
</body>
```

And yes, the tags are there. I had to delete them because stackoverflow doesn't let them show.

Comment: Note that you should indent code with four spaces to get it to show up properly formatted on StackOverflow. I've fixed this for you on this question :)

Comment: unclear what you're asking. why is the variable is declared *after* the `<body>` element, and not before it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JavaScript to set the background color instead of trying to use a JavaScript variable in the HTML, as that is not possible:

```
var colour = "blue";
document.body.style.backgroundColor = colour;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can follow the below practice to randomly change `background-color` of any element.

```html
<body id="bodyTag">

<script>
  function getColor() {
  let codes = 'abcdef0123456789';
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  color += codes[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
  }
  var body = document.getElementById("bodyTag");
  body.style.background=getColor();
</script>

</body>
```